# Div not aligning properly due to image size

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

[image: Wrong alignation]

[image: expected alignation]

Wrong alignation
  expected alignation 
as you can clearly see from picture that whenever i have some pictures with some irregular height i have such alignation problem . i tried changing from css but nothing works any suggestion?
the image is enclosed in  div with only property set is width:100% i tried changing height but didnt work for me. one thing more it works fine if image size is greater than 800x600 pixel

code (only pasting image div and css since i know problem exists in image property)

```
.product .product-image img {
    width: 100%;
}
bootstrap.min.css:
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
bootstrap.min.css:
img {
    border: 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code please, we have no idea what your code structure is.

Comment: Without seeing code, it's hard to tell. But, you can ensure that each product box is the same height, which will make them clear each other. Another option would be to ensure all images are sized to the same width/height. You could also use flexbox or grid to align items properly.

Comment: @Umer, there might be clear fix issue. Share your code.

Comment: i have shared code

Comment: Post more code, with HTML and CSS

Comment: Yes, You have to share the HTML and CSS or you can share the link like jsfiddle or codepen.

Comment: if you guys can go and check it by yourself it will be lot more easy for me 
http://www.karkhana.byethost7.com/shopping-store/online_marketplace_controller/show_products

just select mobiles category and select Apple thats exactly where its showing problem.everywhere else its fine

Comment: it's very difficult to understand without checking the code. Do one thing just add the style clear: both to the parent class of the 3rd image.

Comment: what should i write after clear: ?

Comment: You have to write .parentdiv {clear: both}

Answer (score 0):

After going through 5000+ lines of CSS 
I was able to get something like this.

**[WORKING EXAMPLE](https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/WXLQJO?editors=0100)**

Add these to your files:

**main.css**

```
.product {
  min-height: 350px;
  position: relative;
}

.product .product-info .product-price .price {
  font-weight: 700;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 30px;
  margin-right: 8px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
}

.product .product-info .product-price .price-before-discount {
  text-decoration: line-through;
  color: #d3d3d3;
  font-weight: 400;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 60px;
}

.rateit {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 40px;
}

.name {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 60px;
}
```

**rateit.css**

```
.rateit{
    position:absolute;
}
```

> **NOTE**: I have just added for large size devices, so please use media-query accordingly